# How to pay an Oracle with Link token if I have payable with Ethereum values?

Tags: solidity, remix, randomness, chainlink

First of all, I'm new to this smart contract world, and so I would like to apology if it's a stupid question. I'm programming with Remix and with Solidity as programming language.I have 2 files:

mainfile.sol:

```
[...]
function createSomething(string memory _name, uint _userProvidedSeed) payable public {
        require(msg.value >= productCost);
        //refound user if he/she pays more than the productCost value 
        msg.sender.transfer(msg.value - productCost);
        
        getRandomNumber(_userProvidedSeed);
        _createProduct(_name, randomResult);
    }
[...]
```

and RandomNumberConsumer.sol that is an oracle for generating a random number:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/master/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol"; //import of the VRFConsumerBase for generating random data

contract RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    
    uint256 internal randomResult;
    
    event RequestRandomness(
        bytes32 indexed requestId,
        bytes32 keyHash,
        uint256 seed
    );

    event RequestRandomnessFulfilled(
        bytes32 indexed requestId,
        uint256 randomness
    );
    
    /**
     * Constructor inherits VRFConsumerBase
     * 
     * Network: Kovan
     * Chainlink VRF Coordinator address: 0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9
     * LINK token address:                0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
     * Key Hash: 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4
     */
    constructor() 
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9, // VRF Coordinator
            0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088  // LINK Token
        ) public
    {
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }
    
    /** 
     * Requests randomness from a user-provided seed
     */
    function getRandomNumber(uint256 userProvidedSeed) internal returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        uint256 seed = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(userProvidedSeed, blockhash(block.number)))); // Hash user seed and blockhash
        bytes32 _requestId = requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, seed);
        emit RequestRandomness(_requestId, keyHash, seed);
        return _requestId;
    }

    /**
     * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
     */
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        emit RequestRandomnessFulfilled(requestId, randomness);
        randomResult = randomness;
    }
}
```

the problem here, is that if I generate my product without the payment in ethereum, so by commenting "getRandomNumber(_userProvidedSeed);" it works perfectly and creates the product, obviously without the random number.
When I run it without commenting the above function, remix transaction prompt writes me this:

```
transact to xxx.xxx errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

and in my opinion is a problem with my LINK balance which is 0 probably but generating the random number need to pay a fee to the oracle, as said in the getRandomNumber(..) function.
Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot in advance :P

Comment: " if I generate my product without the payment in ethereum," > could you please explain this?

Comment: read below for further informations, i was wrong by saying the phrase you quote :P sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your contract doesn't have LINK funds to perform the random number generation. Note this require in function `getRandomNumber()`:

```
require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
```

In the same documentation from this example, there is an explanation on how to fund this contract with LINKs as a preliminary step:

https://docs.chain.link/docs/fund-your-contract

Comment: I think it's the right solution but using the chainlink faucet for the kovan testnet doesn't give me link token to my metamask address (connected to kovan obviously) :C

Comment: btw appreciate a lot your help! thanks so much!

Comment: ok, apparently you need to press "add manually a custom token" on metamask and copy-paste this address (on kovan) 0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088 to add the right LINK token. Automatic search by name doesn't work properly :C

Comment: btw was still not working because I should have pressed on remix enviroment->inject web3 and link to metamask then :p

Comment: You are welcome! And you are right: you need to add the custom token addresses manually from testnets in Metamask. As a side note: some Faucets tend to be buggy, so you can also use Uniswap and swap the tokens you need.